# How to change tag name and get attribute using linq-to-xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

this is my xml file

```
<tag>
    <ImageObject Color="BlackWhite" FileRef="12.gif" Format="GIF" Rendition="HTML" Type="Linedraw" />
    <ImageObject Color="BlackWhite" FileRef="32.gif" Format="GIF" Rendition="HTML" Type="Linedraw"/>
    <ImageObject Color="BlackWhite" FileRef="3.gif" Format="GIF" Rendition="HTML" Type="Linedraw"/>
</tag>
```

and the output is something similar to this

```
<tag>
    <img src="12.gif" />
    <img src="32.gif" />
    <img src="3.gif" />
</tag>
```

so far this is my code. but I can't set the attribute of the img because I don't know how to retrieve the attribute of fileref

```
XElement rootImg = XElement.Parse(xml string variable);

IEnumerable<XElement> img =
    from el in rootImg.Descendants("ImageObject").ToList()
    where (string)el.Attribute("Format") != ""
    select el;

foreach (XElement el in img)
{
    el.Name = "img";
    el.RemoveAttributes();
    el.SetAttributeValue("src", "");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no attribute at that point - it's removed one line above. Instead, you can use following:

```
foreach (XElement el in img)
{
    var fileRef = el.Attribute("FileRef");
    el.Name = "img";
    el.RemoveAttributes();
    el.SetAttributeValue("src", fileRef.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First create XElement Object and Parse the XML file ,second take object of Enumerable (img) find formate as el , Now write foreach loop for getting attributes from img (IEnumrable) and setAttributeValue .So Finally your code looks like.

```
XElement rootImg = XElement.Parse(xml string variable);

IEnumerable<XElement> img =
    from el in rootImg.Descendants("ImageObject").ToList()
    where (string)el.Attribute("Format") != ""
    select el;



foreach (XElement el in img)
{
    var fileRef = el.Attribute("FileRef");
    el.Name = "img";
    el.RemoveAttributes();
    el.SetAttributeValue("src", fileRef.Value);
}
```